# How can I replace a whole line of code through Intellij's find functionality?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, replace

I am trying to find an efficient way to remove all the print statements from my source code through multiple files and classes in a project.

So far I have found that you can use Ctrl+Shift+F to find in all code containing System.out.println and Ctrl+Shift+R to replace that code with something else (or nothing in my case) but I have not been able to find a way to replace the ENTIRE line and have only been able to replace the portion of the line that is simply System.out.println

Is there a simple way to get Intellij to select through the end of the line so that I don't need to go into the source code at every mention and manually delete it? I saw in a previous thread to try System.out.println(*); but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution:

> What you are looking for is called `Structural Search/Replace`.
>
> It is not very well documented but it is **Extremely Powerful** once
>   you grok it completely.
>
> There are a few examples in the `Existing Templates` that you can
>   probably modify and learn from, the following will do what you are
>   asking for now.

#### Here is how:

Go to the Menu: `Edit -> Find -> Replace Structurally` and use the following `Search Template`.

```
System.out.println($EXPRESSION$);
```

Check `Case Sensitive` and make `File Type` = `Java Source`

Set the `Scope` of the search to `Project Files` for everything.

If you want to just remove it all you can just make sure the `Replace Template` field is blank.

You could comment them all out with a `Replace Template` of `//System.out.println($EXPRESSION$);` or `/* System.out.println($EXPRESSION$); */`

#### Better Solution:

> Use the `Structural Search/Replace` to add `private static final
>   Logger L = LoggingFactory($Class$.class);` to all the classes with the
>   `System.out.println()` statements.

Then replace all the `System.out.println($EXPRESSION$);` with `L.info($EXPRESSION$);`

You can even do things sophisticated things like the following:

*This is just an example idea, the body of the `catch` needs to only have the the `System.out.println($EXPRESSION$)` a more sophisticated block to grab other expressions and keep them would be an exercise for the reader.*

```
try {
  $TryStatement$;
} catch($ExceptionType$ $ExceptionRef$) {
  System.out.println($EXPRESSION$);
}
```

with

```
try {
  $TryStatement$;
} catch($ExceptionType$ $ExceptionRef$) {
  L.error($EXPRESSION$);
}
```

#### Best Solution:

> Always use a `Logger` instead of `System.out.println()` in
>   **everything**. Even in `scratch` classes used for experimenting, they eventually end up in production code at some point!

Comment: Wow, I would say I am a relatively novice programmer and this is a surprisingly easy solution which worked without much hassle. I'm not entirely sure that I grasp what you mean with the logger, though. Do you mean write to a file instead of printing to the console so I can look over the logs later if need be?

Comment: logging can be to the console and a file or files at the same time, and takes less time than `System.out.println()` eradication later.

Answer (score 29):

Use regex replace with newlines.

<kbd>crtl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>, check "Regular expression", then

```
Text to find: .*System\.out\.println.*[\r\n]+
Replace with: <leave blank>
```

`.*` won't match newline chars, but the expression `[\r\n]` does (on all Os).

Comment: Still no dice. Just for clarification here --> https://i.imgur.com/qXbmLjq.png is what I got with the added *         and here --> https://i.imgur.com/MLVyyRU.png  are some of the examples of things I'm looking for

Comment: @JarrodRoberson firstly, the regex `[\r\n]+` means *any* number of *any* combination of line endings, so it will work as expected no matter what OS you're on. Secondly, this will work for most instances you'll find of `println`, which almost always appear solo on a line. And it works - IMHO there is nothing "unfortunate" about it.

Comment: it will not match `System.out.\nprint(\n"somecrap"\n);\n`. I had to eradicate 30K+ lines of such madness because contractors found out they could use this trick to get past Sonar reports. And the `\n` were in different places sometimes before the `print` sometimes before the `(` sometimes both. A naive regex would not match them and one that might would be hideously complex and would still probably not match them all and would probably have lots of false positives in any case. Structural Search/Replace found them all regardless of trickery with the new lines and not a single false positive.